# Capitalize each letter in an array that is a vowel

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to capitalize each letter in an array that is a vowel. I have:

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
```

and if `vowels` includes the character, then I will upcase it. I did:

```
["a", "b", "c"].each do |char|
  if vowels.include?(char)
    char.upcase
  end
end
```

but it returns `["a", "b", "c"]`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new string with `upcase`, and throwing it out. You need to use `upcase!` to convert the string to upcase.

```
["a", "b", "c"].each do |char|
  if vowels.include?(char)
    char.upcase!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each). [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) will evaluate the block, but throw away the result. This is why you end up with `["a", "b", "c"]`, or the contents of the original array that you want to check for vowels.

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
["a", "b", "c"].map do |char|
  char.upcase if vowels.include?(char)
end.compact
```

[`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) creates a new array, where each element is the result returned by the block. [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) will remove any `nil` values, or those that are not vowels (the block did not return true).

Comment: This does transform `"a"` to `"A"`, but it also removes `"b"` and `"c"`.

Comment: @Stefan that's true, although it's unclear from the original question what the user wants to do with none-matching values.